# (How) can I use a dynamic volume with mongodb in GKE through gitlab?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I am attempting to create a MongoDB through the gitlab-ci using `helm` (a DB similar to the postgres offering by Gitlab). Using only `helm` charts, I am trying to enable the service. [I am deploying on my own cluster but eventually it will be on a cluster that I do not have direct `kubectl` rights to.]
I am adapting the setup based on this video [walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cwjtN3gkD4&feature=youtu.be).

I am receiving this error:

```
wait.go:53: [debug] beginning wait for 7 resources with timeout of 5m0s
wait.go:216: [debug] PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: angular-23641052-review-86-sh-mousur/review-86-sh-mousur-mongodb
```

This is the `application.yml` file:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "chart.fullname" .}}-deployment
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: {{ template "chart.fullname" .}}-example
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "chart.fullname" .}}-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  example
          image: angular-example:1.0.1
          env:  
            - name: MONGO_URL
              value: mongodb://{{ template "mongodb.fullname" . }}.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/{{ .Values.DbName }}
```

Currently, this is for testing - and the database is very small based on a few JSONs.
How can I move to use dynamic storage for the interim ***using only helm charts*** i.e. *without access to kubectl*?

Comment: Have you referred https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolumeclaim

Comment: Could you provide more details about your local cluster where you are testing? Also, the link in your original comment is not properly formatted, so we are not quite sure which reference are you referring.

Comment: The PVC is created dynamically, you'll need to actually debug why the PVC is not being mounted to your pod. This is not necessarily an issue with helm, the deployment config, or the pvc config. Use kubectl to describe the pod and the pvc, and get events in the namespace to see if there is an error when mounting the pvc. Check stackdriver logs as well to see if there were errors when mounting the disk

Comment: What is the output of a PV describe command? and what is the output of pod trying to get that PVC bound?
If storage class is standard I assume you are using the default GCEPersisentDisk Volume PlugIn.

In case this is true. Unfortunately this does not support ReadWriteMany. Typically ReadWriteMany is used when the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes. You can found more here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: I do not have access to kubectl.